# Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource Error (Amazon Elastic Beanstalk / Spring Boot / JSF + Primefaces)

Tags: spring-boot, jsf, primefaces, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I created an app using Spring Boot, JSF + Primefaces. I deployed it to Amazon Elastic Beanstalk, and set the environment variables that project needed to use.

When I tried to access my website, I got this error message:

```
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Thu Mar 04 07:21:33 UTC 2021
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
/login.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource
```

Here is my Faces Config (as java class):

```
    package com.jsf;



@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.jsf")
public class HelloJsfApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HelloJsfApplication.class, args);
    }

    // JSF Configration Başlangıc
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean<FacesServlet> facesServletRegistraiton() {
        ServletRegistrationBean<FacesServlet> registration = new ServletRegistrationBean<FacesServlet>(
                new FacesServlet(), new String[] { "*.xhtml" });
        registration.setName("Faces Servlet");
        registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        registration.addUrlMappings("*.xhtml");

        return registration;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletContextInitializer servletContextInitializer() {
        return servletContext -> {
            servletContext.setInitParameter("com.sun.faces.forceLoadConfiguration", Boolean.TRUE.toString());
            servletContext.setInitParameter("primefaces.THEME", "bootstrap");
            // Primefaces client browser tarafında kontrol edilebilme örneğin textbox 10
            // karakter olmalı vs..
            servletContext.setInitParameter("primefaces.CLIENT_SIDE_VALIDATION", Boolean.TRUE.toString());
            // Xhtml sayfalarında commentlerin parse edilmemesi.
            servletContext.setInitParameter("javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS", Boolean.TRUE.toString());
            // primefaces icon set için
            servletContext.setInitParameter("primefaces.FONT_AWESOME", Boolean.TRUE.toString());
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletListenerRegistrationBean<ConfigureListener> jsfConfigureListener() {
        return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<ConfigureListener>(new ConfigureListener());
    }

    // JSF Configration Sonu
}
```

my faces config file under webapp/WEB-INF folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">
    <application>
        <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
        
    </application>

</faces-config>
```

and as you see, all my xhtml files are under webapp folder:

[image: xhtml files]

my application.properties file (using java params):

```
server.servlet.context-path = ${CONTEXT_PATH}
server.port = ${PORT}

spring.datasource.url = ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL}
spring.datasource.username = ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password = ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD}

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = ${SPRING_JPA_DATABASE_PLATFORM}

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = ${SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO}
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=${SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_LOB_CREATION}

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVERCLASSNAME}
```

and here are java parameters that I defined on Amazon (I will not post db params for security reasons):

```
PORT=5000
CONTEXT_PATH=/
SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVERCLASSNAME=org.postgresql.Driver
...
```

and so on.

Really I run out of solutions. With same packaged jar, I deployed to Heroku with same environment parameters, and it works flawlessly.

Where I am doing wrong with Amazon Elastic Beanstalk?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

Maven, does not add *.xhtml files inside "jar" package.
Here is the ss of decompiled version of jar packaging (with jd-gui)

[image: jar decompiled]

..and here is the ss of war packaging:

[image: war packaging]

so if you are think that you did everything correct during development and managing after, check the packaging type.